# My product variation is not shown on the entity form

Tags: entities, forms, commerce, 9

I have many products coming from a migration. This is working for most of the products, but for some of them, the **/commerce/modules/product/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/SingleVariationWidget.php** widget is empty.

First, I thought that the product didn't have any variation. Turns out, it does.

After some digging, I've found that the *formElement* function inside *SingleVariationWidget* isn't retrieving only the variation product.

This variable is getting first an instance of my product, then my product variation.

```php
$variation = !$items->isEmpty() ? $items->first()->entity : NULL;
```

To bypass this, I've added this patch, but it's a patch, and I still don't know why it happened.

```php
$variation = !$items->isEmpty() ? $items->first()->entity : NULL;

if (!$variation) {
  $param = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product');
  $variation = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->create([
    'type' => reset($this->getFieldSetting('handler_settings')['target_bundles']),
    'langcode' => $items->getEntity()->language()->getId(),
  ]);
  if ($param) {
    $idProduct = $param->id();
    $product = Product::load($idProduct);
    if ($product->getDefaultVariation()) {
      $variation = $product->getDefaultVariation();
    }
  }
}
```